# VBA - How to retrieve XML keys within keys in debug.Print

Tags: xml, excel, vba

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EmpDetails>
    <Employee>
      <Name>ABC</Name>
      <Dept>
        <Software1> VBA </Software1> 
        <Software2> Windows </Software2>
      </Dept> 
      <Location>New Delhi</Location>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
      <Name>XYZ</Name>
      <Dept>
        <Software1> VBA </Software1> 
        <Software2> Windows </Software2>
      </Dept> 
      <Location>Chennai</Location>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
      <Name>IJK</Name>
        <Dept>
          <Software1> VBA </Software1> 
          <Software2> Windows </Software2>
        </Dept> 
        <Location>Bangalore</Location>
    </Employee>
</EmpDetails>
```

VBA

```vb
Sub Test()

Dim userBeanList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim userbean As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim beanChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xDoc.Load ("C:\data\xml.xml")

Set userBeanList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//EmpDetails/Employee")

For Each userbean In userBeanList
    For Each beanChild In userbean.ChildNodes
        Debug.Print beanChild.nodeName & ":" & beanChild.Text


    Next beanChild
Next userbean

End Sub
```

My code currently prints from the xml, the following:

```
Name:ABC
Dept:VBA   Windows
Location:New Delhi
Name:XYZ
Dept:VBA   Windows
Location:Chennai
Name:IJK
Dept:VBA   Windows
Location:Bangalore
```

I want it to actually print

```
Name:ABC
Dept:VBA   Windows
Location:New Delhi
Name:XYZ
Software1:VBA   
Software2:Windows
Location:Chennai
Name:IJK
Software1: VBA
Software2: Windows
Location:Bangalore
```

Comment: i reformatted your XML code with proper indentation ... you should see it once it is accepted .... your XML file is not formatted for what you want. `XYZ` is not a sub-tag of `ABC` ... you will have to choose which tags will print in which order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my first Example, I simply added another level (grandChild) to your loop.

```
Sub Example()

    Dim userBeanList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim userbean As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim beanChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim grandChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    xDoc.Load ("C:\Users\best buy\Desktop\xml.xml")

    Set userBeanList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//EmpDetails/Employee")

    For Each userbean In userBeanList
        For Each beanChild In userbean.ChildNodes
            Debug.Print beanChild.nodeName & ":" & beanChild.Text
            For Each grandChild In beanChild.ChildNodes
                If Not Left(grandChild.nodeName, 1) = "#" Then Debug.Print grandChild.nodeName & ":" & grandChild.Text
            Next
        Next beanChild
    Next userbean

End Sub
```

---

Here is an Example of using recursion that will print all the branches and leaf of the XML without knowing the actual structure.

```
Sub RecursiveExample()
    Dim userBeanList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    xDoc.Load ("C:\Users\best buy\Desktop\xml.xml")

    Set userBeanList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//EmpDetails/Employee")
    RecursivePrintNodes userBeanList
End Sub

Sub RecursivePrintNodes(NodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList)
    Dim child As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    For Each child In NodeList
        If Not Left(child.nodeName, 1) = "#" Then Debug.Print child.nodeName & ":" & child.Text
        If child.ChildNodes.Length > 0 Then RecursivePrintNodes child.ChildNodes
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks great - I hope It can be applied to any xml !

Comment: I'm optimistic that the Recursive pattern should work on any XML.  It's basically the same pattern used to list all folders and subfolders in a directory.