# Can I return all items in a node?

Tags: xml, vba

This is a sample of my node

```
  <Validation>
    <Audit Node="Site" Count="1" />
    <Audit Node="Resident" Count="3" />
    <Audit Node="Lease" Count="3" />
    <Audit Node="Unit" Count="3" />
    <Audit Node="OpenCharges" Count="15" />
    <Audit Node="SureDeposit" Count="0" />
  </Validation>
```

The following code snippet

```
Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument60
If Not xmlDoc.LoadXML(indata) Then
    Err.Raise xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xmlDoc.parseError.reason
End If
Set list = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Response/FileContents/Collections/Validation/Audit")
For Each node In list
    Set attr = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("Node")
    If (Not attr Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.Print attr.BaseName & " " & attr.Text
    End If
    If (node.HasChildNodes) Then
        For Each childNode In node.ChildNodes
            Debug.Print childNode.BaseName & " " & childNode.Text
        Next childNode
    End If
Next node
```

as expected returns

```
Node Site
Node Resident
Node Lease
Node Unit
Node OpenCharges
Node SureDeposit
```

Is there a way to return all NamedItems?

So I would want to return NODE,COUNT
I need to be able to save the named items and the corresponding value to an array for later use. This is the smaller node in my project. I have several and one has 50+ nameditems.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Your code already returns node names. Do you want to return other attributes too? Do you know the names of the attributes you want to return? If not, do you want to return all attributes of `Audit` nodes?

Comment: in the above example node I want to be able to return the names NODE and COUNT without having to name them in this line Set attr = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("Node"). I know I can identify the number of items using list.Item(1).Attributes.Length. but how to get the name?

Comment: @dotNet .. I think a better answer is yes I want to return all attributes of Audit node. I am trying for a = 1 to list.Item(1).Attributes.Length debug.print (what to use here) next a

Comment: My answer to [VBA - How to retrieve XML keys within keys in debug.Print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352451/vba-how-to-retrieve-xml-keys-within-keys-in-debug-print/46353625#46353625) shows how you can recursively iterate over XML.

Comment: I solved my issue but I think I took the long way around. Please see my solution and maybe it is a better explanation of what I was trying to do and my guess is there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are asking for two things here. To answer how to return all nodes:

```
Function GetAllNodes() As Collection
    Dim theNodes As New Collection

    Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument60
    If Not xmlDoc.LoadXML(indata) Then
        Err.Raise xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xmlDoc.parseError.reason
    End If
    Set List = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Response/FileContents/Collections/Validation/Audit")
    For Each Node In List
        Set attr = Node.Attributes.getNamedItem("Node")
        If (Not attr Is Nothing) Then
            Debug.Print attr.BaseName & " " & attr.Text
        End If
        If (Node.HasChildNodes) Then
            For Each childNode In Node.ChildNodes
                Debug.Print childNode.BaseName & " " & childNode.Text
                '*
                '* Add node and content to collection
                '*
                theNodes.Add childNode.BaseName & " " & childNode.Text
            Next childNode
        End If
    Next Node
    Set GetAllNodes = theNodes
End Function
```

Comment: No sir.. That is doing exactly what the code I posted is doing. I was hoping there was a way to output both base names "Node and Count" without having to name them

Answer (score 0):

```
Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument60
If Not xmlDoc.LoadXML(indata) Then
    Err.Raise xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xmlDoc.parseError.reason
End If
Set list = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Response/FileContents/Collections/Validation/Audit")
ReDim AuditN(list.Item(1).Attributes.Length)
ReDim AuditV(list.Length, list.Item(1).Attributes.Length)
For a = 0 To list.Item(1).Attributes.Length - 1
    SplString1 = Split(Mid(list.Item(1).XML, InStr(list.Item(1).XML, " "), Len(list.Item(1).XML)), "=", (list.Item(1).Attributes.Length * 2))(a)
    Debug.Print Split(SplString1, " ", 2)(1)
    AuditN(a) = Split(SplString1, " ", 2)(1)
Next a
nodeCounter = -1
For Each node In list
    nodeCounter = nodeCounter + 1
    For a = 0 To UBound(AuditN()) - 1
        Set attr = node.Attributes.getNamedItem(AuditN(a))

        If (Not attr Is Nothing) Then
            AuditV(nodeCounter, a) = attr.Text
        End If
        If (node.HasChildNodes) Then
            For Each childNode In node.ChildNodes
                Debug.Print childNode.BaseName & " " & childNode.Text
        Next childNode
        End If
    Next a
Next node
```

With this solution I have an array with the element name and one with the element value that I can use later. I would suspect there is a cleaner way to do this?